# Embedding Vevo videos not working in Chrome and safari

Tags: youtube, jwplayer

I am using embedded Vevo videos in JW player.  It is working fine in Firefox, but it displays an error on Chrome and Safari:

> error loading Youtube embedding not allowed

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/2121212121.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container-video">
 <script type='text/javascript'>
          jwplayer("container-video").setup({
            file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s",
            width: 545,
            height: 350
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: Ethan, this my server link.. "http://54.201.45.212/testvideo.php" If you run this videos on chrome and safari it will not run but it will successfully run on firefox

Comment: Interesting, it seems like this particular video is not embeddable through the YouTube API, but it seems to vary on a per browser basis. Maybe something changed with how Vevo videos are embeddable through their API?

Answer (score 0):

Vevo has a special license with YouTube hence, it is not possible to embed them. Let me explain this: You may have seen in YouTube Studio that there is an option that you can toggle to allow or disallow embedding video on the website. This is what Vevo does to its video, Vevo has disallowed embedding.

[Youtube Embedded Allow-Disallow Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzWRq.jpg)